# Getting a value, which has been given to a TikZ key

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tikz-circuit-lib, circuits

I'm trying to write a package based on TikZ, and this is the problem I'm currently stumbling upon.

Let's assume, that I have a key, for example `/tikz/circuit symbol unit`, which executes some code.

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the value, which has been passed on to this key to use it somewhere else within my code?

I want to use the value, which has been passed on to the `/tikz/circuit symbol unit` key to draw an arc of the appropriate radius in the foreground of the shape I've made.

So instead of `\pgfpatharc{50}{130}{6pt}` I'd have something like this `\pgfpatharc{50}{130}{[some function to get the value passed to circuit symbol unit key]}`.

Here's the code for the shape - you can skip to the "Drawing the arc" section of the code, which is at the very end:

```
   % The measurement gate shape - rectangle with an arc inside
   \pgfdeclareshape{meter}
   {%

     % All anchors are taken from the 'rectangle' shape:
     \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}]%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{center}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{mid}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{base}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{north}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{south}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{west}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{east}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{mid west}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{mid east}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{base west}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{base east}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{north west}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{south west}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{north east}%
     \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{south east}%
     \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}]%

     % Drawing a white background
     \backgroundpath{
     \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}
     \pgfsetfillopacity{1}
         \pgfsetfillcolor{white}
         \pgfusepath{fill}
     }       

     \foregroundpath
     {
       % Drawing the rectangle

    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
     {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}
     {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}
     {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}
     {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}
     {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}
     {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}





    \northeast
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \pgf@ya=-\pgf@y

   %
   %    
   % Drawing the arc

   \def\arcstart{\pgfpoint{.8\pgf@xa}{.7\pgf@ya}}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\arcstart}    

   %
   %
   % This is the line i'm interested in - how do i put in the value passed on to
   % /tikz/circuit symbol unit key instead of 6pt. It should be something like
   % \pgfpatharc{50}{130}{some function to get the value passed to circuit symbol unit}
   \pgfpatharc{50}{130}{6pt}    

    }
```

Comment: Most certainly it is. Would you mind providing the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that they can work with? It will speed up the likelihood of getting you the answer you're after.

Comment: With your own key, it is simple (your key can define a macro with the value passed as argument). With any other key, you can _patch_ this key (for example, via the `.forward to` handler) to memorize the parameter.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Why not `\pgfkeysvalueof{}` rather than messing around patching the key? If you want to use it a lot, I can see the convenience of a macro, but otherwise, it seems simply to just retrieve the value.

Comment: Please provide a complete example. You are already using `\pgfkeysvalueof{}` so maybe I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: What's the point of commenting line endings if you immediately leave a line blank?

Comment: @cfr A lot of keys don't store its argument or use special macros to store it.

Comment: @cfr I you use `.code` handler to define a key (for example `/tikz/circuit symbol unit`), you can't use `\pgfkeysvalueof{}` to get the value(s) which has been passed to this key.

Answer (score 1):

Your code already retrieves the values of keys using `\pgfkeysvalueof{}` so perhaps my understanding of your question is overly simple-minded.

However, you can certainly use that method:

```
    \pgfpatharc{50}{130}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuit/symbol/unit}}%
```

Where `/tikz/circuit/symbol/unit` is a dummy key I created since you didn't provide a complete example and I have no idea what you're actually doing.

```
\tikzset{%
  circuit/symbol/unit/.initial=10pt,
}
```

Then, for example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [meter, draw] {};
  \node [xshift=15pt, circuit/symbol/unit=4pt, meter, draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image: variable dimension thingy]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{meter}
{%
  % All anchors are taken from the 'rectangle' shape:
  \inheritsavedanchors[from={rectangle}]%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{center}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{mid}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{base}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{north}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{south}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{west}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{east}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{mid west}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{mid east}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{base west}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{base east}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{north west}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{south west}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{north east}%
  \inheritanchor[from={rectangle}]{south east}%
  \inheritanchorborder[from={rectangle}]%
  \backgroundpath{%
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners{\southwest}{\northeast}%
    \pgfsetfillopacity{1}%
    \pgfsetfillcolor{white}%
    \pgfusepath{fill}%
  }%
  \foregroundpath
  {%
    \pgfpathrectanglecorners
    {\pgfpointadd{\southwest}%
      {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
        {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}%
    {\pgfpointadd{\northeast}{\pgfpointscale{-1}%
        {\pgfpoint{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
          {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}}}}%
    \northeast
    \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
    \pgf@ya=-\pgf@y
    \def\arcstart{\pgfpoint{.8\pgf@xa}{.7\pgf@ya}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto{\arcstart}%
    \pgfpatharc{50}{130}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/circuit/symbol/unit}}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{%
  circuit/symbol/unit/.initial=10pt,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [meter, draw] {};
  \node [xshift=15pt, circuit/symbol/unit=4pt, meter, draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```